# How to create a Locale based on language code?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently, I am displaying language name, based on user settings locale

```
static func getDisplayLanguage(_ languageCode: String) -> String? {        
    let current = Locale.current

    return current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: languageCode)
}
```

But, now, I wish to display language name, based on the language locale, and independent from user settings locale.

For instance,

```
"es" (Spanish language code) will displayed as "Española"
"en" (English language code) will displayed as "English"
"zh" (Chinese language code) will displayed as "中文"
...
```

May I know, how I can achieve so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the locale declaration in your function to use the locale for the given language code

```
 let current = Locale(identifier: languageCode)
```

The whole function but compressed:

```
static func getDisplayLanguage(_ languageCode: String) -> String? {
    Locale(identifier: languageCode).localizedString(forLanguageCode: languageCode)
}
```

Comment: And to exercise this code, you can use: `for languageCode in Locale.isoLanguageCodes {
    print("\(languageCode): \(getDisplayLanguage(languageCode) ?? "nil")")
}`